# "Unknown Pair" exception when using StreamTransformer for BinaryObject

Tags: ignite

I have a cache which store BinaryObject actually in a cluster(2 nodes). Ignite version is 2.1.0.
If I don't use any StreamReceiver(include StreamTransformer), there is no problems when adding lots of BinaryObject data with following code:

```
IgniteDataStreamer<Long,BinaryObject> ds = ignite.dataStreamer(CACHE_NAME);
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
long i = 0;
long count = 1000000;
while(i++<count){
    builder.setField("id", i);
    builder.setField("name", "Test"+i);
    builder.setField("age", random.nextInt(30));
    builder.setField("score", random.nextDouble()*100d);
    builder.setField("birthday", new Date());
    ds.addData(i, builder.build());
    if(i%10000==0){
        System.out.println(i+" added...");
    }
}
```

But now, I want to modify my BinaryObject data value before adding, so I tried StreamTransformer like this:

```
ds.receiver(new StreamTransformer<Long,BinaryObject>(){
    @Override
    public Object process(MutableEntry<Long, BinaryObject> entry, Object... arguments)
            throws EntryProcessorException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Long key = entry.getKey();
        BinaryObject value = entry.getValue();
        BinaryObjectBuilder builder = value.toBuilder();
        //want to change the value of "name" field
        builder.setField("name", "Modify"+builder.getField("name"));
        entry.setValue(builder.build());
        return null;
    }
});
while(...){
    //... original code to build BinaryObject data and call ds.add method
}
```

Unluckily following exceptions occurred:

```
[09:52:36] Topology snapshot [ver=61, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=2.7GB]
10000 added...
20000 added...
30000 added...
40000 added...
[09:52:39,174][SEVERE][data-streamer-#54%null%][DataStreamerImpl] DataStreamer operation failed.
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to finish operation (too many remaps): 32
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5.apply(DataStreamerImpl.java:869)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5.apply(DataStreamerImpl.java:834)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:382)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblock(GridFutureAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblockAll(GridFutureAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:473)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:461)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$Buffer$2.apply(DataStreamerImpl.java:1572)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$Buffer$2.apply(DataStreamerImpl.java:1562)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:382)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblock(GridFutureAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblockAll(GridFutureAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:473)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:461)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:967)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=-1496463502]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7229)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=-1496463502]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:392)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:342)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:686)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1755)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:161)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:41)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:125)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerEntry$1.getValue(DataStreamerEntry.java:96)
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.StreamTransformer.receive(StreamTransformer.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerUpdateJob.call(DataStreamerUpdateJob.java:137)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6608)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:959)
    ... 4 more
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `ClassNotFoundException` because `DataStreamer` internally tries to deserialize stored `BinaryObject`. To make it use `BinaryObject`s directly, you should invoke `ds.keepBinary(true)` before using it.

Another problem you have in your code is the way you use result of `entry.getValue()`. Actually, `entry`, passed to `process` method represents a record previously stored in cache, so you'll most likely get null value there. If you want to get a newly-assigned value, you should use `arguments[0]` value.

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried to invoke ds.keepBinary(true) before using it as you said. The "ClassNotFoundException" problem no longer exist.

Comment: entry.getValue() really return null value and arguments[0] is what I want. But I don't understand that arguments may be several objects so what does each of them mean?

Comment: @CrazyRen this behavior is described in the javadoc: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/stream/StreamTransformer.html
So, actually only one object is possible to appear there.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much again.